# Javascript Array 2 keys return one value

Tags: javascript, arrays

this is really hurting my brain so I hope somebody can help.

I have some data from a spreadsheet that has 2 axis'

```
AGE     50      51      52

£7      £1,497  £1,479  £1,458
£8      £1,746  £1,725  £1,701
£9      £1,996  £1,972  £1,944
```

the user will input there age into a input box on the page, and click next, i save this into a variable

```
var age = 50;
```

the user is then present with another input box and can input a value from 0 - 100

i then save this into another variable

```
var ammount = 10;
```

with the two values i need to search the array for the corosponding values to return the answer.

the data i have is currently in a spread sheet, i need to take this data from the spreadsheet put this into an array in java script.

with the two values i need to find the relevant answer.

Comment: Enters what? Where? This question is beyond vague at the moment - what is the full context?

Comment: Do you need to read the values from the spreadsheet? Are the values hard coded? Console or GUI? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Please give more information. Do we click on 1725 and get 8/51 or what?
Here is a JSObject you might use `var tbl = {
  "age": [50, 51, 52],
  "rates": {
    "7": [1497, 1479, 1458],
    "8": [1746, 1725, 1701],
    "9": [1996, 1972, 1944]
  }
}`

Comment: Your question is extremely vague and lacks detail. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try somethink like:

```
  var row1 = {
        "50" : "£1,497",
        "51" : "£1,479"
        // etc
  }
  var dictionary = {
        "£7": row1
        // etc
  }
```

Next, call `dictionary["£7"]["50"]`